# "Cached element do not exists in DOM" when run Appium with Robot Framework

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I'm working on automated test using **Appium** with **Robot framework** on Android device. I create schedule run on **Jenkins**. My test flow is entering some data in page A and submit, then switch to page B to check the result and switch to page A to enter a new data. I repeat this loop for around 10+ time. Everything works fine in around 4-5 rounds but after that there show up an error :

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Cached element 'By.xpath:
> //android.widget.TextView[@text='Limit']' do not exists in DOM anymore

The `TextView` is in the page A. I monitored the robot and saw that the `TextView` was shown up but the robot did not see it. I tried restart the device but the problem is not solved. I search through the internet and found some who facing the same issue but they use different programming language like Java or Python. I have no idea what I have to do next.

Development Tools : 
**Appium** version: 1.21.0 
**Robot Framework** version: 4.1.2 (Python 3.10.0 on win32)

Answer (score 0):

First I do not use Robot Framework, but the code should be similar according to this https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/try-except-finally-exception-catching-and-handling.

Second, I'm not sure if this is the best way to get around this. I think there is something you can do with the expected conditions class to get around this in a "cleaner way" but I'm not quite familiar with it enough to show/tell you.  Instead what I've done is something like this...

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
while some_limiting_factor:
        try:
            # logic for submitting page A, assertions for page B
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            element = driver.find_element('By.xpath: //android.widget.TextView[@text='Limit']' )
```

As much as I want to cache elements in appium, it seems that the service itself does NOT want you to, at least not in my experience. Getting a fresh element(s) every time seems to ensure a "slow but steady" test. Hopefully someone can show me the deep appium secrets one day.